# Sorting Scientific Number With Unix Sort

Tags: linux, unix, sorting, numbers

I tried to sort these number with Unix sort, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    2e-13
    1e-91
    2e-13
    1e-104
    3e-19
    9e-99
```

This is my command:

```
sort -nr file.txt
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Use python, sorted, key = lambda x: float(x). Python can be used for one-liners. What version of Python is pre-installed?

Comment: @Hamish Grubijan - You probably should have posted that as an answer, +1. Its a lot more portable than relying on GNU extensions.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use `-g` (long form `--general-numeric-sort`) instead of `-n`. The `-g` option passes the numbers through `strtod` to obtain their value, and it will recognize this format.

I'm not sure if this is available on all implementations of `sort`, or just the GNU one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was initially GNU centric, but I can't think of a `sort` that doesn't offer it now. Might be problematic, but I think only on very old systems.

Comment: This did not sort 0 and 0.1 properly for me. Had to add LANG=C to my pipe `... | LANG=C sort -g`

Answer (score 8):

if your `sort` doesn't have `-g`, another way.

```
$ printf "%.200f\n" $(<file) |sort -n |xargs printf "%g\n"
1e-104
9e-99
1e-91
3e-19
2e-13
2e-13

$ sort -g file
1e-104
9e-99
1e-91
3e-19
2e-13
2e-13

$ printf "%.200f\n" `cat file` |sort -n |xargs printf "%g\n"
```

Answer (score 7):

Just do two things:

1. Use `-g` (or `--general-numeric-sort`) to make `sort` treat Exp-numbers correctly.
2. Use `LC_ALL=C`. The `sort` is very sensible to locale if your data may contain some language-specific symbols except ASCII. So using  `LC_ALL=C` is the universal approach for *every* case you use the `sort`, it makes `sort` to treat the input stream as binary, and you wouldn't have any problems.

So the universal solution is:

`cat file.txt | LC_ALL=C sort -gr | less`

Also I made an alias for sort in my `.bashrc` file:

`alias csort="LC_ALL=C sort"`

for much convinient use.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a not fully tested version of Python script. Supposed usage:

```
sort_script.py file.txt
```

Unfortunately I developed this on Windows, and with 2 different versions of Python installed I cannot test it properly. Warning: requires newest Python (with, print functions added or changed). Note: back_to_file flag can be an optional parameter, although with Unix you can always redirect ... even in Windows you can.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.1
# Note: requires newer python

import sys

#Remove this line:
sys.argv = ('', 'file.txt')

assert(len(sys.argv) == 2)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as fin:
    lines = fin.readlines()

lines_sorted = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: float(x))

back_to_file = False # Change this if needed

if back_to_file:
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as fout:
        fout.writelines(lines_sorted)
else:
    for lns in lines_sorted:
        print(lns, end='') # Suppress new line
```